# Avada uploading zip folder to godaddy cpanel and extracting it to the correct wp-content or wp-theme folder

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

Hello I would like to know if anyone can help me with the correct placement of files on godaddy cpanel. I bought Avada zip files and would like to upload it to cpanel and place it in the public_html folder to the correct wp-content folder so the theme works. Can anyone help me to navigate to the right folder to place the Avada theme? It seems like a very simple task but I can't figure it out. I can't find video on it either. Thank you for your help. Eva

Comment: Did you see their documentation? A quick Google search resulted these links: 1. Video guide: https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/videos/install-avada-via-wordpress-video/ 2. Text guide: https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/install-update/how-to-install-avada-via-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Lets write from Beginning. Download Avada From themeforest. Unzip it first there you will find a folder name avada.zip thats the theme only file. Or from themeforest you can download wordpress installation file only. Then go to Godaddy and then browse your server file manager.

Go to public_html and then upload wordpress.zip folder which you have to download from WordPress.org . Then unzip it. you will get a unzipped folder named wordpress. if you want to install wordpress in root just go inside and move all files in publick_html and delete wordpress folder.

Then browse wp-content>themes and upload avada.zip there and unzip it.

Then follow WordPress regular installation guide you can find available online.

Comment: Niamul thank you so much  for your instructions.  After I download the Wordpress via godaddy cpanel and upload the avada.zip files to the cpanel - file manager - public html - wp-content - wp theme do I still have to enter the DATABASE ID  when I download the Wordpress or the wordpress and avada files are automatically linked together. I will create informational website with avada theme with godaddy cpanel and the wordpress pages in the wordpress dashboard with avada theme.  Thank you again for your help.. I understand it by 90%.. I need to clarify the database connection. Eva